# About Switch Case in Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash

I'm newbie in bash script, I want to create a switch case without "break" like java code below

```
switch(choice) {
    case 1: 
           System.out.println("1");
    case 2:
           System.out.println("2");
}
```

choice = 1

```
output: 1
        2
```

so ... how can I do that in bash script :(

Answer (score 2):

Prior to `bash` 4, you couldn't; at most one block of commands in a `case` statement would be executed. `bash` 4 introduced the `;&` case terminator, which causes fall-through.

```
case $choice in
    1) echo 1 ;&
    2) echo 2 ;;
esac
```

Comment: @hoaithy92: if you run `bash --version`, is it version 3.x or 4.x?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it version is 4.3.1

Comment: @hoaithy92: OK; that should support the `case` … `esac` notation that @chepner showed.  The `switch` notation you showed doesn't apply to Bash; it might be valid in C shell, or something similar might be valid (I neither know nor care).

Comment: So that no way to do like `switch` that I showed, right ? :(

Comment: @hoaithy92: try calling your script with `bash`, maybe you had called it with `sh` or its shebang is `/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/bash`, and your `/bin/sh` wasn't linked to `/bin/bash`.